# If $a+b+c+d=2$, find the maximum value of $(1+a+b)(1+c+d)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+b+c+d=2$, find the maximum value of $(1+a+b)(1+c+d)$

My Attempt:
$$a+b+c+d=2$$
Now,
\begin{align}(1+a+b)(1+c+d)&=1+c+d+a+ac+ad+b+bc+bd\\
&=1+(a+b+c+d)+ac+ad+bc+bd\\
&=1+2+ac+ad+bc+bd\\
&=3+ac+ad+bc+bd\end{align}

How do I proceed further?

P.S: Edit after fractal1729 comment.

Comment: One cannot find the exact value of $(1+a+b)(1+c+d)$ given $a+b+c+d$.  Perhaps you are looking for the maximum value?

By the way, you might as well set $x = a+b$, $y = c+d$ to get $x+y = 2$ and the expression in question as $(1+x)(1+y)$.

Comment: It can take all values in $(3,4)$ if the variables are positive.  If negative numbers are allowed, more values are possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a+b+c+d=2$
$$\implies (1+a+b)+(1+d+c)=4$$
 Thus by AM-GM inequality,
$$\frac{(1+a+b)+(1+c+d)}{2}\ge\sqrt{(1+a+b)(1+c+d)}$$
Thus $$(1+a+b)(1+c+d)\le(\frac{4}{2})^2$$
 Thus maximum value of $(1+a+b)(1+c+d)$ is 4. It is attained when $$a+b=c+d=1$$.

Comment: This will work since (1+a+b) and (1+b+c) must be +ve for getting maximum value. If one of them is negative we do not get the maximum value.

Comment: It is just an upper bound. How can I say that it is the maximum?

Comment: It is attained when a+b=c+d=1.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Basti's answer, except this substitution makes it even quicker to get the range of possible values.  Use $x = c+d-1$; then $$(1+a+b)(1+c+d) = (2-x)(2+x) = 4-x^2 \leq 4.$$  Furthermore, if $a,b,c,d$ are positive, $x$ ranges between $-1$ and $1$, so $x^2$ ranges between $0$ and $1$, so $4-x^2$ ranges between $3$ and $4$.  Done!

Comment: $a+b=11,\quad b+c = -9,\quad (1+a+b)(1+c+d) = -96.$

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Yes that is possible, but the lower bound of 3 is correct if a,b,c,d are positive.  Also with the OP's correction to the question, the lower bound (and hence the assumption) is no longer required, as the answer is simply the maximum which is 4.

Comment: The answer is wrong.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain why it is wrong, you seem to have gotten the same answer

Comment: The claim "$x$ ranges between $-1$ and $1$" is wrong.

Comment: Here is justification for that claim: $x=c+d-1 \geq -1$ since $c, d \geq 0$, and $1-x=1-(c+d-1) = 2-c-d = a+b \geq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $c+d-1 \leq 1$.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Since $a+b=2-(c+d)$, put $x=c+d$ and we have
$$ (1+a+b)(1+c+d)=(3-x)(1+x)$$
Now it is easy to see that the expression can take multiples values while $a+b+x=2$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b=x,\quad c+d = y,$ then
$$x+y=2,\quad 1+x+y+xy\le 1+x+y+xy = 1 + x+y + \left({x+y\over2}\right)^2 - \left({x-y\over2}\right)^2 \le 4.$$